# Inserting data in database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have following files:

1. Student.sql
2. index.jsp
3. sampleReport.jsp
4. StudentServlet(com.ydp.controller)
5. StudentDao(com.ydp.dao)
6. StudentDaoImpl(com.ydp.dao.impl)
7. Student(com.ydp.domains). 
    
   My database connection is **jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample** [app on APP].

**StudentDaoImpl.java**:

```
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {
private DataSource ds;
private Connection con;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
private ResultSet rs;
public StudentDaoImpl() {
}
@Override
public void create(Student student) throws SQLException, NamingException {
    long id = getID();
    ds = getStudentDS();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO STUDENT(ID,STUDENTNAME,EMAIL,AGE,COUNTRY) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, student.getStudentName());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, student.getEmail());
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, student.getAge());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, student.getCountry());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
}
@Override
public List<Student> findAll() throws NamingException, SQLException {

    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ds = getStudentDS();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM STUDENT");
    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(rs.getLong("ID"));
        student.setStudentName(rs.getString("STUDENTNAME"));
        student.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        student.setAge(rs.getInt("AGE"));
        student.setCountry(rs.getString("COUNTRY"));
        list.add(student);
    }
    con.close();
    return list;
}
@Override
public Student find(long id) throws NamingException, SQLException {

    Student student = null;
    ds = getStudentDS();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=?");
    preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        student = new Student();
        student.setId(rs.getLong("ID"));
        student.setStudentName(rs.getString("STUDENTNAME"));
        student.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        student.setAge(rs.getInt("AGE"));
        student.setCountry(rs.getString("COUNTRY"));
    }
    con.close();
    return student;
}
@Override
public void edit(Student student) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    ds = getStudentDS();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE STUDENT SET STUDENTNAME=?, EMAIL=?, AGE=?, COUNTRY=? WHERE ID=?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, student.getStudentName());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, student.getEmail());
    preparedStatement.setInt(3, student.getAge());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, student.getCountry());
    preparedStatement.setLong(5, student.getId());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
}
@Override
public void delete(long id) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    ds = getStudentDS();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=?");
    preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
}
private DataSource getStudentDS() throws NamingException {
    Context c = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource) c.lookup("java:comp/env/StudentDS");
}
private long getID() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    long id = 0;
    ds = getStudentDS();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX (ID) FROM STUDENT");
    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        id = rs.getLong(1);
    }
    id++;
    con.close();
    return id;
} }
```

**StudentDao.java**:

```
public interface StudentDao {
 public void create(Student student) throws SQLException, NamingException;
 public List<Student> findAll() throws SQLException, NamingException;
 public Student find(long id) throws SQLException, NamingException;
 public void edit(Student student) throws SQLException, NamingException;
 public void delete(long id) throws SQLException, NamingException;
}
```

**Error : I can't save data into database**.
  My friend told (try with try catch at public void create(Student student) and also getID. Don't use throw the exception) I use try catch but it doesn't work.

Comment: show error log and where is your connection create code?

Comment: Check what values you are getting in ds and con in create method. Try to check whether you are able to connect to database first.

Comment: I want to send my whole project file to you.

Comment: Have you tried calling Connection#commit before you close it?

Comment: The error "I can't save data into database" is not a normal error message. Please describe if you get an exception (and if so: post the stacktrace), or more clearly describe your problem.

Comment: Your DAO implementation is by the way not thread safe nor resource leak safe. Try finding a more decent DAO tutorial